# Facing many edge cases while sanitizing long text in Swift

Tags: swift, string, replace, split

I currently have a very long text with numbers, words, symbols (i.e. ", ?, ;, :, ', -, +, etc). I'm trying to strip down all numbers and symbols from the text so I purely have a text with just words.

My expectation is (ignore semantics in below example):

```
(BEFORE Sanitization) John's pet (Parson) is sleeping in a car: a BMW. 

(AFTER Sanitization)  John s pet Parson is sleeping in a car a BMW
```

Here is my code in an attempt:

```
static func splitText(text: String) -> [String] {
    let lowerCasedString = text.lowercased()
    let sanitizedString = lowerCasedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+|:", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
    let splittedStringArray = sanitizedString.split { [",", "[", "]", " ", " - ", "(", ")", ".", "/"].contains( String($0)) }.map(String.init)
    print(splittedStringArray)
    
    return splittedStringArray
}
```

When I run the function, I'm still seeing many symbols and words like `John's`. How can I improve this function to strip all symbols possible?

## I essentially just want alphabetical letters left in my text.

Plus, is there any sanitization framework in Swift for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer makes use of `NSString`.

```
import Foundation

public extension String {
  var sanitized: String {
    return self
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
      .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
  }
}

print("John's pet (Parson) is sleeping in a car: a BMW.".sanitized) // John s pet Parson is sleeping in a car a BMW
```

It works by passing through the `String` twice; first, to replace occurences of non-alphanumeric characters and second, to replace multiple spaces by single spaces.

Comment: @DennisVennik, thanks for the answer! I have a further question. I found another edge case which is "-". Let's say there's a word "part-time". With current solution, it's going to strip "-" away from the word when I actually want to keep it as "part-time". How would you write a regex in order to include "-" ?

Comment: @user7418039 You add `\\-` to `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"` to make `"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-]"`.